# Injection in custom validator

Tags: jsf-2, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dependency injection in FacesValidator (JSF Validation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/dependency-injection-in-facesvalidator-jsf-validation)

Maybe, I'm missing something basic - but can't I use injection in a custom validator class in order to use the message resources? The following code gives me a null on `msg`, so injection obviously does not work, but why? And if it's not possible, how can I access the message resources? All examples I found so far, use hard coded text in validator messages which is not very useful for localization.

```
public class BirthdateValidator implements Validator {
    @Inject
    private transient ResourceBundle msg;

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
            if ( [some validation fails] ) {
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(msg.getString("validator.birthday"));
                message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this post in the search result I did before posting, but the main tag "spring" let me skip it. - Ok since I only need to access the message bundle, how would I access it without injection? That way I could avoid changing all occurrences of all my validators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As to why it doesn't work that way, see this answer: [How to inject in @FacesValidator with @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/dependency-injection-in-facesvalidator-jsf-validation/7572413#7572413). In a nutshell, annotate it `@Named` instead of `@FacesValidator` and reference it in `<h:inputXxx validator>` or `<f:validator binding>` as `#{birthdateValidator}` instead. The problem is caused by an oversight by JSF/CDI guys. This is fixed in upcoming JSF 2.2.

---

> *Ok since I only need to access the message bundle, how would I access it without injection?*

Evaluate it programmatically using `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`:

```
ResourceBundle msg = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{msg}", ResourceBundle.class);
// ...
```

You can even pick a specific key:

```
String msg = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{msg.key}", String.class);
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Read resource bundle properties in a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655540/read-i18n-variables-from-properties-file-in-a-bean)

Comment: Thank you for the new insight, works fine.