# Why can JSF resource bundle var be used differently with f:loadBundle and faces-config

Tags: jsf-2, resourcebundle

I have one property file linked both ways (using f:loadBundle and faces-config.xml) both with different var names. So it would look like the following:

datatypes.properties:

```
A=first
B=second
C=third
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>datatypes</base-name>
    <var>myProp</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

myPage.xhtml:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="datatypes" var="prop"/>
```

in myPage.xhtml I make a list of all the keys from the property file. What I can't seem to understand is that when I use `#{prop}` in the code below it works but when I replace it with `#{myProp}` the list no longer displays.

```
<h:form>
 <h:selectManyListbox id="list">
 <f:selectItems value="#{myProp}"></f:selectItems>
 </h:selectManyListbox>
</h:form>
```

I figure this means the variables in both cases are not the same behind the scenes but I would appreciate it if someone could explain (or point me to an explaination) in what way they are different. I would ideally like to just use `#{myProp}` without having to pull the keys out in code and store them in a list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `<f:loadBundle>` and `<resource-bundle>` are different ways to load properties with difference being in their access scopes. The latter has by the way the additional benefit that the bundle is also [injectable in a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655540/read-i18n-variables-from-properties-file-in-a-bean) by `@ManagedProperty("#{myProp}")`

Using `<resource-bundle>` in faces-config.xml creates a ***global*** resource bundle which can be accessed anywhere in your application. This is implemented through a `java.util.ResourceBundle` instance.

Using `<f:loadBundle>` in your view creates a ***view-specific*** resource bundle which is accessible only within that view. The tag handler implements this using an internal implementation of a Map. This is as specified in the [VDL of the tag](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/f/loadBundle.html):

> Load a resource bundle localized for the Locale of the current view,
>   and expose it as a **java.util.Map** in the request attributes of the
>   current request under the key specified by the value of the "var"
>   attribute of this tag.

Now since you're trying to use the values from datatypes.properties through `<f:selectItems>`, you'll get the said exception. This is because the **value** attribute for the tag [should evaluate to a Collection or an array](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html).

> Value expression pointing at any **Collection** or **array**. The member
>   elements may be instances of SelectItem or any Java Object.

So in order to use the global bundle instance, you first have to convert the same into a `List<SelectItem>` inside your backing bean before using it.

**NOTE:** You can verify the above cases by setting a breakpoint in the `initializeItems(Object)` method in the `com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator` class. This is, of course, assuming that you're using the Mojarra implementation.

Comment: I don't see how any preference is taken since I am using different variable names for the gobal resource bundle (myProp) and the view-specific resource bundle (prop). I just removed the view-sepcific resource bundle decalaration and `#{myProp}` still does not work. I get an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you were using it for a selectManyListBox. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and update Vrushank. I think the different implementations for a global vs. view-specifc resoruce bundles threw me off initially, but it's clear to me now after reading your response. Thanks!