# execute code before parsing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, localization

Is that possible to execute some java code before jsf parsing?

My use case: let's say, I have several `outputText` that are defined in external property file:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['my.example.label']}"/>
```

And after each of this `outputText` I want to have another outputText with value of `msg` key (for debugging purposes).

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['my.example.label']}"/>
<h:outputText value="my.example.label"/>
```

And I don't want to add it manual to each label, but write some code, that can detect `#{msg[...]}` fragments, extract key and add it after original tag.

Is it possible with JSF?

Comment: You could do two things. Create a custom component that takes the 'key' as an attribute and inside it both displays the key and the resolved `msg` if in debug mode or just the label when not in debug/developer mode. But you could also create a resource resolver (the 'alternative' part in the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655540/read-resource-bundle-properties-in-a-managed-bean and have it return the key and resolved value when in developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component that extends `HtmlOutputText` (`<h:outputText>`). Here an example that i have used for something similar, but showing all expressions (beans, resurces and implicit objects), not only resource variable:

The custom component:

```
@FacesComponent("com.mycompany.component.CustomOutputText")
public class CustomOutputText extends HtmlOutputText {

    public static final String ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = "value";

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return "com.mycompany.component.customFamily";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return (String) getStateHelper().eval(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE);
    }

    public String getNotEvalValue() {
        return (String) getValueExpression(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE).getExpressionString();
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        getStateHelper().put(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

        writer.startElement("span", this);
        writer.append(getValue());
        writer.endElement("span");

        writer.startElement("p", this);
        writer.append("[expression: " + getNotEvalValue() + "]");
        writer.endElement("p");
    }
}
```

The taglib:

```
<namespace>http://com.mycompany/custom-components</namespace>
<tag>
    <tag-name>customOutputText</tag-name>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.mycompany.component.CustomOutputText</component-type>
        <renderer-type>com.mycompany.component.CustomOutputText</renderer-type>
    </component>
    <attribute>
        <name>value</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

Register in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/custom.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And, to test, a simple managed bean (in this case, CDI)

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getSample() {
        return "sample text from bean";
    }   
}
```

In the xhtml include the taglib, and use the component:

```
<custom:customOutputText value="#{myBean.sample}" />
```

And the output is:

```
sample text from bean

[expression: #{myBean.sample}]
```

Note that the component will generate 2 html tags, 1 `<span>` and 1 `<p>`, consider this for app css styles.

Comment: Nice solution. Sort of what I wrote in my comment... But... OP wants to display the 'key' from the expression, not the full expression. You could implement parsing the expression (removing the `#{msg['` part and the `']}` part but then it only works for the msg variant and not e.g. if also a 'field'  (e.g. `#{field['my.other.key']}` is used. And it only works for this specific tag (OP should better have used an `outputLabel`, but that is another issue.) But thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks, there are many ways to do that, the example is only one of many. Glad to help!